# shema_plus with rails migration: make combined columns unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema

I'm using the shema_plus gem in rails, and I want to make it so I am unable to duplicate data into my database if the combination of two columns is the same.

shouldn't this work?:

```
t.string :name, null: false, index: { with: :deleted_at, unique: true }
```

':deleted_at' is definitely a field in my migration.

but this allows me to enter in the same name twice on the mysql side.

also, here is some info that mysql gives me:

```
Index: index_plans_on_name_and_deleted_at
Definition:

Type    BTREE
Unique  Yes
Columns name
    deleted_at
```

EDIT_____________________________________________________

It looks like I needed a default value for deleted_at, like :

```
t.datetime :deleted_at, default: '2000-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the gem, but you can directly achieve this in ActiveRecord using:

`validates :name, :uniqueness => {:scope => :deleted_at}`

assuming you want the combination of `name` and `deleted_at` to be unique.

Comment: yes thanks!!... just trying to lock it down on both ends.  It looks like I have to have a default value for deleted_at, like : t.datetime :deleted_at, default: '2000-01-01'